# No HTTP triggers found (Azure Functions)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to complete the cloud resume challenge and I am stuck on the following steps:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFSjq.png)

I have created an azure function and a http_trigger, when I use the default code given for the http trigger it works absolutely fine, but this is not what I want to achieve.

When I update the code to try integrate it with my CosmosDB, just by writing a simple value to it and deploy it to my function, the http trigger just totally disappears from the dashboard meaning I can not execute it rendering it pointless. See attached code I am trying to use:

''''
import azure.functions as func
import logging

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, outputDocument: func.Out[func.Document]) -> func.HttpResponse:
logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

```
# Hardcoding the name to "YourName"
name = "Charlie"

# Your data to be stored in Cosmos DB
data_to_store = {
    "name": name,
    "additional_property": "value"  # Add any additional properties you want to store
}

# Use the Cosmos DB output binding to store the data
outputDocument.set(func.Document.from_dict(data_to_store))

return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
```

''''

I have updated the CosmosDbConnectionString to my primary string in local.settings.json as advised on MSLearn.

I have the following in my requirements.txt folder:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IalS7.png)

Tried with various different code examples and all of them come back with http trigger error (https://i.stack.imgur.com/madSP.png)

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your Function logs, there must be an error saying the reason the Function is not indexed.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) It's really important to provide properly formatted text (just edit your question and use the `{}` button to insert a text block, or surround your text block in triple-backticks). Also be sure to provide a [mcve], not just a block of code - it's hard to tell what your specific issue is.

Comment: @chuns Please Share your code in text format, ``` newline <your code> newline ```

Comment: Tried to update code thats best I can do, wont format the top lines for some reason:

Comment: Had to use the below site to get it working, not sure why it would not work with Python v2 https://evan-wong.medium.com/create-api-using-azure-function-with-python-and-azure-cosmos-db-afda09338d82

Answer (score 0):

> No HTTP Trigger found.

This error is due to improper syntax format of http trigger in your `function_app.py`. When using python model V2 proper format should be followed.

In your code these are missing which is important for function to identify http trigger.

```
app =func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
```

For reference check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python-v2,isolated-process,nodejs-v4,functionsv2&pivots=programming-language-python).

For CosmosDB output binding reference check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-output?tabs=python-v2,isolated-process,nodejs-v4,extensionv4&pivots=programming-language-python).

> **Note :**
> In CosmosDB output binding, use `container_name` in place of `collection_name` and `connection` in place of `connection_string_setting`.

My code:
**`function_app.py`:**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app =func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.cosmos_db_output(arg_name="outputDoc",database_name="Testdb",container_name="test_container",connection="CosmosDbConnectionString")
@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest, outputDoc: func.Out[func.Document]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = "Vivek"

    data_to_store={
        "id": "123",
        "Name": name,
        "Data": "Test"
    }

    outputDoc.set(func.Document.from_dict(data_to_store))

    return func.HttpResponse("Document successfully processed.", status_code=200)
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

```
8:01:11 PM cosmosdbpyfunc: Number of directories 75
8:01:11 PM cosmosdbpyfunc: Number of ids (unique uids + gids) 1
8:01:11 PM cosmosdbpyfunc: Number of uids 1
8:01:11 PM cosmosdbpyfunc:  root (0)
8:01:11 PM cosmosdbpyfunc: Number of gids 1
8:01:11 PM cosmosdbpyfunc:  root (0)
8:01:11 PM cosmosdbpyfunc: Creating placeholder blob for linux consumption function app...
8:01:11 PM cosmosdbpyfunc: SCM_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE placeholder blob scm-latest-cosmosdbpyfunc.zip located
8:01:11 PM cosmosdbpyfunc: Uploading built content /home/site/artifacts/functionappartifact.squashfs for linux consumption function app...
8:01:11 PM cosmosdbpyfunc: Resetting all workers for cosmosdbpyfunc.azurewebsites.net
8:01:11 PM cosmosdbpyfunc: Deployment successful. deployer = ms-azuretools-vscode deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
8:01:35 PM cosmosdbpyfunc: Syncing triggers...
8:01:40 PM cosmosdbpyfunc: Querying triggers...
8:01:49 PM cosmosdbpyfunc: HTTP Trigger Urls:
  http_trigger: https://cosmosdbpyfunc.azurewebsites.net/api/http_trigger
```

[image]

```
Document successfully processed.
```

[image]

```json
{
    "id": "123",
    "Name": "Vivek",
    "Data": "Test",
    "_rid": "sycqAIfM4i4BAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/sycqAA==/colls/sycqAIfM4i4=/docs/sycqAIfM4i4BAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"64000074-0000-0700-0000-65b3c3370000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1706279735
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just like you advised the OP in your comment under the question, regarding formatting text output: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - this includes output, as well as what's seen in data explorer. Many reasons are enumerated in that paged I linked to.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I added the output of my Data explorer in text format too before the image.

Comment: Updated my answer with output in text too